# What are all the tld's recognized by NSDataDetector?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, tld, nsdatadetector

When testing Cocoa data detector I found that `forecast.io` isn't picked up but `www.forecast.io` and `forecast.com` are.

What are all the top level domains found by NSDataDetector without prefixing them with `www.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote about [how to pick an Apple friendly TLD](http://stevemoser.org/blog/2013/04/21/how-to-pick-an-apple-friendly-tld/) and my findings are recounted below.

I just took the [text file from ICANN](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) and prepended all the extensions with 'example.' and the only ones detected at least in my locale(US) were these:

Uppercase:

```
example.com
example.EDU
example.EU
example.GOV
example.LY
example.NET
example.ORG
```

Lowercase:

```
example.ar
example.at
example.au
example.be
example.br
example.ca
example.ch
example.cn
example.de
example.dk
example.edu
example.es
example.eu
example.fi
example.fr
example.gov
example.gr
example.hk
example.hu
example.il
example.is
example.it
example.jp
example.kr
example.lu
example.ly
example.ma
example.mx
example.net
example.nl
example.no
example.nz
example.org
example.pt
example.ru
example.se
example.sg
example.th
example.tn
example.tr
example.tw
example.ua
example.uk
example.us
```

Comment: Blog post link is broken

Answer (score 1):

From my own testing, it looks like anything with `www.` on the front will be detected.

As an update to Steve's answer, here are the lowercased tld's that were detected for me, as of Nov 1, 2016:

```
example.ar
example.at
example.au
example.cc
example.ch
example.cn
example.co
example.com
example.de
example.dk
example.edu
example.es
example.eu
example.fi
example.fm
example.fr
example.gov
example.gr
example.hk
example.hr
example.hu
example.ie
example.il
example.info
example.io
example.is
example.it
example.kr
example.lu
example.ly
example.ma
example.me
example.mx
example.net
example.nl
example.no
example.nz
example.org
example.pt
example.pw
example.rs
example.ru
example.se
example.sg
example.si
example.th
example.tn
example.tr
example.tw
example.ua
example.uk
example.us
```